# É possível usar o Inner Join em varias colunas da mesma tabela em um Select?

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join

No banco existem 2 tabelas relacionadas.

**Colaboradores**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Eventos** (aqui faz a entrada de tempo de treinamento por colaborador):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso saber o total de tempo de treinamento de cada setor. O Select abaixo funciona, porém apenas para a coluna C1. Preciso percorrer as outras colunas também (c2, c3, c4, c5 etc), no entanto eu ainda não descobri como fazer.

```
SELECT SUM(eventos.tempo)
FROM colaboradores
INNER JOIN eventos
ON colaboradores.id = eventos.c1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na clausula `ON` do `JOIN` você pode usar o operador `IN` e comparar com todas as colunas que contém o `id` do colaborador. Como você quer saber o total de tempo por setor, também é necessário adicionar um `GROUP BY` pelo setor:

```
SELECT colaboradores.setor, SUM(eventos.tempo) tempoTotal
FROM colaboradores
INNER JOIN eventos
  ON colaboradores.id IN (
    eventos.c1, eventos.c2, eventos.c3, eventos.c4, eventos.c5,
    eventos.c6, eventos.c7, eventos.c8, eventos.c9, eventos.c10
   )
GROUP BY colaboradores.setor
```

**Resultado**

```
+----------------+
|setor|tempoTotal|
|-----|----------|
|    A|      1780|
|    E|      2260|
|    P|      2860|
|    Q|      2860|
|    X|      1660|
+----------------+
```

Veja funcionando no [**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/363d7f/2).

**Informação Adicional**

Armazenar os colaboradores do evento dentro da tabela `eventos` não é o ideal para a [normalização de dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados). Isso pode gerar diversos problemas, um deles é que você limita em 10 a quantidade de colaboradores em um evento, se um dia houver o 11º, você terá um grande retrabalho a fazer.
Como a relação de `eventos` e `colaboradores` é `N:N` é necessário criar uma terceira tabela para referenciar.

Mas neste caso, como a tabela `eventos` só contém uma coluna, você poderia fazer o inverso, um colaborador por linha e para cada colaborador armazenar o tempo:

```
CREATE TABLE eventos(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  idcolaborador INT,
  tempo INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_eventos_colaboradores FOREIGN KEY (idcolaborador) REFERENCES colaboradores (id)
);
```

Dessa forma seu `SELECT` ficaria assim:

```
SELECT colaboradores.setor, SUM(eventos.tempo) tempoTotal
FROM colaboradores
INNER JOIN eventos
  ON colaboradores.id = eventos.idcolaborador
GROUP BY colaboradores.setor
```

Veja funcionando no [**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e4078c/1).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar quantas condições desejar no Inner join

```
SELECT colaboradores.id, SUM(eventos.tempo) 
FROM colaboradores INNER JOIN eventos ON colaboradores.id = eventos.c1 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c2 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c3 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c4 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c5 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c6 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c7 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c8 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c9 
                                      OR colaboradores.id = eventos.c10 
GROUP BY colaboradores.id
```

O group by é para fazer a soma por pessoa